# How does if condition finds unique letter in the string?

Tags: java, string, find, unique

I am newbie here!!

I am unable to understand how "s.indexOf(s.charAt(i), s.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) + 1) == -1 "

checking for unique letter in the string. Below is the code,

```
   String s = "leetcode";
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

      if (s.indexOf(s.charAt(i), s.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) + 1) == -1) {
          return i;
      }
   }
  return -1;
```

Thank you for your help!

I am trying to find the unique character in the given string. I came across this code. I am trying to understand how it work!

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `String.indexOf(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,int))? --- The code does not do what you say it does.

Comment: @Turing85: I'm not convinced of that, actually.  It seems to look for a second `indexOf` the char, which would prove whether or not the `char` appears only once in the string.  I think it would work.

Comment: @LouisWasserman so why does it return `0` on the word `"leetcode"`, if there are non-unique characters in it? And why does it return `3` on `"leelcode"`?

Comment: This code tries to find index of *first* unique character in string `s`. The condition can be expresses like "if currently checked character has no more same characters *after its **first** occurrence*".

Comment: If we are at index `i`, this means that we see `s.charAt(i)` for the first time. If this was not the case, and we saw same letter at index k < i, we would have returned k. Thus `s.indexOf(s.charAt(i))` can be reduced to `i`, and entire condition to: `if (s.indexOf(s.charAt(i), i + 1) == -1)` => we check if there is character `s.charAt(i)` starting from position `i + 1` => if there is none, we found index of non-repeating character

Comment: @Turing85: For "leetcode", it successfully prints 0, which is the _index_ of the first unique character.  It does incorrectly match on `leelcode`, it's true, though.

Comment: For `leelcode` it returns 4 which is index of `c`. Demo: https://ideone.com/b1qevc

Comment: @Pshemo true that So it basically prints the index of the 1st unique character.

Comment: The above code will return the index of the unique character. If there is no unique character return -1.

Answer (score 0):

For a rather verbose function like this, the best thing to do is break it down to the smallest possible computation (effectively).

Please refer to the following code snippet:

```
public class App {

    private static int unique(String s) {

        /** The String (non-primitive) is an array of chars (primitive).
         * So, it'll be iterated with a loop. S.length () is the length of the char array.
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            /** This will return the char element of the index i -> public char charAt(int index) */
            char chatAtI = s.charAt(i);

            /** Follow the println logs to see what's happening, or use a debugger on an IDE. */
            System.out.println("chatAtI -> " + chatAtI);

            /** Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character
             * or -1 if the character does not occur.
             */
            int charIndex = s.indexOf(chatAtI) + 1;
            System.out.println("charIndex -> " + charIndex);

            /** The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified character(s) in a string.
             * It's an overloaded method.
             * In the if condition, you're also using the variant which [1] returns the index of the first char occurrence
             * and [2] start the search at the specified index or -1 if the character does not exist.
             * The moment a unique occurrence is found, it'll return the index;
             * meaning - "if the current char doesn't repeat in the char array, return its index and exit the method."
             * Keep in mind the +1 above is what does the trick, as if that character doesn't repeat indexOf() returns -1.
             */
            if (s.indexOf(chatAtI, charIndex) == -1) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /** l is the first unique occurrence. Therefore, its index, 0, is returned. */
        System.out.println(unique("leetcode"));
    }
}
```

Articles for further reading:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-char-to-string-to-char-array
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/charat-in-java-how-to-use-the-java-charat-method-2/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-indexof/

I hope this made sense. If not, let me know, as I can edit the answer and give more context.